# Passing c# global variable to sql query

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-5, global-variables

I have a Auto class as follows

```
namespace UI.Controllers
{
    public class Auto
    {
       user = 'raven';

    public static string user
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Now since i have mentioned the variable as a global variable, i am able to use this variable in other .cs files by using it in this way.

```
string getusername = Auto.user;
```

The problem exist while i am trying to query the SQL table with this username. Here is what I intend to do.

`SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE NAME = [put user details here];`

The `[]` bracket sign indicated the username. i.e raven should be placed there dynamically

I tried below variations but it didn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE NAME= "@Auto.user";
SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE NAME= "Auto.user";
SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE NAME= Auto.user;
SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE NAME= & Auto.user &;
SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE NAME= & "Auto.user" &;
```

It gives me an error stating that `The name Auto doesn't exist in current context`

Can someone suggest me if I am trying the right way. ?

Here is the actual SQL query

```
readonly string USERNAME = @"SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE NAME = ";


public List<Users> GetUserName()
    {
        string query = USERNAME + "@name";
        return this._users.Get(query, new { name = Auto.user });
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the full code that shows how you are trying to execute the query?

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot- all the queries are put in one file for the project. segregation of things have been done. i wil put it whatever i could. gimme a sexc

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot- added the code. pls have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to pass the Auto.user value to the query variable just use string.Format

```
readonly string USERNAME = @"SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE NAME = {0}";

public List<Users> GetUserName()
{
    var query = string.Format(USERNAME, Auto.user);
    return this._users.Get(query);
}
```

Without more insight about the way the query is done inside the query executer I can't figure out another way of doing it. If you update the question with more information about _users type and implementation I can give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks Diogo, i understand and thanks for the answer. can you also in general let me know how to pass a global variable to a normal sql query. i will try to then work out on the complex side of my code

Comment: It always depends on the way you're doing things and the ORM you're using, but one thing is for sure, global variables are sign of bad things, you should avoid them as much as possible.